# Angular order of selected option in multiple mat-select

Tags: angular, angular-material, dropdown, mat-select

I want to be able to keep track on the order of selected options in multiple mat-select. How can I implement this use case?

Let's say first I select 'Onion' then 'Mushroom' and then 'Pepperoni'. I want to be able to get from mat-select the selected options in this order ['Onion', 'Mushroom', 'Pepperoni'].
And if I then deselect 'Mushroom' and select 'Extra cheese', I want to get the selected options in an array like ['Onion', 'Pepperoni', 'Extra cheese'].

[image]

Comment: that depends on how you bound the items. if you its set via a formControl i would use valuechanges if its template binding i would you ngOptionChanged if none of those i would use selectionChanged from mat-select it self. Granted all mentioned will give you all selected items. so you would have to write logic that find the latest added in the list and add them to a variable. as well if anything removed remove that from that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subscribe to MatSelect's `optionSelectionChanges`. It emits `MatOptionSelectionChange` objects. On this stream you can use rxjs's `scan`.

**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
  <mat-select multiple #toppingSelection>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping"
      >{{topping}}</mat-option
    >
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**TS**

```
export class SelectMultipleExample implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('toppingSelection')
  toppingSelection: MatSelect;

  toppingList: string[] = [
    'Extra cheese',
    'Mushroom',
    'Onion',
    'Pepperoni',
    'Sausage',
    'Tomato',
  ];

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // TODO: unsubscribe
    this.toppingSelection.optionSelectionChanges
      .pipe(
        scan((acc: string[], change: MatOptionSelectionChange) => {
          if (change.source.selected) {
            return [...acc, change.source.value];
          } else {
            return acc.filter((entry) => entry !== change.source.value);
          }
        }, [])
      )
      .subscribe((selectedValues: string[]) => console.log(selectedValues));
  }
}
```

**Stackblitz**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-baamvq?file=src/app/select-multiple-example.ts

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom compare function that returns zero since the sorting is similar to how Array.prototype.sort works. A zero return value assumes the items being compared are sorted hence mat-select will return the selected option values in the order in which they were selected. E.g.

When using mat-select in multiple selection mode, bind to the  [sortComparator] @input of mat-select to use your noCompareFunction as below:

**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
  <mat-select multiple #toppingSelection [sortComparator]="noCompareFunction">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping"> 
      {{topping}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**TS**

```
//Our function returns 0
noCompareFunction(){ return 0;)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use `FormControl`

create `FormControl` in your **component.ts**

```
toppings = new FormControl('');
toppingList: string[] = ['Extra cheese', 'Mushroom', 'Onion', 'Pepperoni', 'Sausage', 'Tomato'];
```

then bind it in your mat-select in **component.html**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

or,

you can also add `(selectionChange)=selectionChanged($event)` in your `mat-select`

```
<mat-select [formControl]="toppings" (selectionChange)=selectionChanged($event) multiple>
```

Comment: question was not how to bind the data, but keep track on the order of selection.