# disable autoSort result in Multiple selection mat

Tags: angular, sorting, angular-material

i want to disable auto sort  in  Multiple selection mat M result when it return
html

```
<div class="input pt-2 w-full">
  <mat-form-field class="w-full">
    <mat-select formControlName="staffInvolved"  multiple >
      <mat-option #matOption *ngFor="let participant of listManager" [value]="participant" >{{participant.nameShow}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

ts

```
  formGroup = this.fb.group({
    staffInvolved: [[], [Validators.required]],
  });
```

First I chose NV040 then I chose NV001
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kG7zt.png)

the result [i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSWq4.png)

I want it to show up in the order I choose rather than sorting alphabetically it should be  [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hrJQ.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular order of selected option in multiple mat-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74543480/angular-order-of-selected-option-in-multiple-mat-select)

Comment: Please add the code as text and not as images.

Answer (score 0):

A mat-select always return an array "sorted", so you need "a work-around"

Imagine you not have an array of string else an array of object with two properties, value and order

```
  toppingList: any[] = [{value:'Extra cheese',order:0},
                        {value:'Mushroom',order:0},
                        ...];
```

Now you can, when make click change the property "order". For this, declare a var "order"

```
order:number=0;
```

And use

```
<mat-select formControlName="toppings" multiple>
  <mat-option
    (click)="topping.order=order;order=order+1"
    *ngFor="let topping of toppingList;let i=index"
    [value]="topping"
    >{{topping.value}}</mat-option
  >
</mat-select>
```

See [a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u4infp-brvmcm?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.ts)

See that the value of the form control steel will be "ordered", but now you can use, in submit, some like

```
  submit(form:FormGroup)
  {
    const data={...form.value,
      toppings:form.value.toppings
                 .sort((a:any,b:any)=>a.order-b.order)
                 .map((x:any)=>x.value)
      }
      console.log(data)
  }
```